# What's the difference between glBindRenderbufferOES and glBindRenderbuffer?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

What does that OES stand for? Was it referring to OpenGL ES 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no glBindRenderbuffer function in OpenGL ES 1.

To use renderbuffers you must use framebuffer extension that provides glBindRenderbufferOS function.

In OpenGL ES 2 framebuffers are in core specifiction, so you don't have extension, but have the core function glBindRenderbuffer.